# Рисование графиков (точки разрыва)

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, есть сложность с построением графиков функций, которые имеют иррациональные точки разрыва (типа `tg(x)` в `Pi/2`). Если точка разрыва - целое число, то проблем нет: в результате цикла срабатывает исключение и я просто не заношу в словарь пару `(X;Y)`, но с иррациональными числами сложнее, потому как попасть в них точно невозможно. Как быть в этом случае? 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Раздражает не совсем это: пусть у нас шаг = 0.01, тогда  значения тангенса в точках 1.56, 1.57, 1.58 = 92.62, 1255, -108.64. Если соединить эти точки, график получится, мягко сказать, некрасивый, весь график сольется в последовательность вертикальных линий.

Comment: Нда.. как-то не подумал что в "дырку" ж можно и "не попасть".

Вопрос интересный, я по свободе попробую поковырять и написать ещё что-то.

Comment: Видимо абсолютно неграмотный метод, но первое что приходит в голову.



Если между точками i и i+1 функция меняет знак, то проверим ее поведение поведение между точками i-1,i и i+1,i+2. Если она росла (убавала) как на i-1,i , так и на i+1,i+2, то между i и i+1 рисовать линию не надо (точка разрыва).

Comment: Видимо не совсем понял , но вот такой простой пример : sin(x) на отрезке [3.13;3.16] с шагом 0.01 . При переходе через 3.14 на 3.15 знак меняется .Как на отрезке [3.13;3.14] так и на [3.15;3.16] синус монотонно убывает , но это не говорит о существовании точек разрыва по-моему

Comment: Да, Вы правы, что написал не будет работать. Нужно отслеживать еще и то, что на i+1,i+2 стала меньше (если росла), чем на i-1,i. Аналогично для убывающей - стала больше.

Comment: Не. Этот метод имеет право на жизнь, но нюансы:
- нужно отсекать значения, которые можно считать бесконечностью, но для этого нужен довольно маленький шаг. Переход знака - возможно, но не обязательно. По сути мы не учитываем всё, что ушло за пределы экрана (когда "прошлая" точка вне области рисования).
- это должна быть отключаемая опция))

Comment: В общем выскажу наверное последнее мнение по-этому вопросу : поймать  иррациональные точки разрыва делая выводы об убывании/возрастании этой точки мне кажется неправильным , никакой закономерности в этом нет . Походу единственный способ : это сделать ещё 2 поля y_max и у_min , которые будет вводить пользователь и просто отсекать всё , что выходит за эти значения . Просто видимо не зря эти 2 поля есть практически во всех онлайн построителях (http://school35.ucoz.ru/grapher/grapher_e.htm)

Comment: Тогда все становится намного легче

Answer (score 2):

Обычно строят как. 
Считают точку, запоминают. Считают следующую - и соеденяют прямой.

Дырки обычно делают методом обработки исключений УДАЛЯЯ запомненную точку (вас же раздражает вертикальная линия (обратный ход), в графике тангенса?)

Маткады и прочие работают с полуаналитическим поиском области определения. Это крайне сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Правильный результат можно получить и следующим образом - ваша текущая программа работает на сетке значений с некоторым шагом `step`. *Соответственно, **красивую картинку** можно получить либо путем увеличения разрешения сетки, либо путем интерполяции соседних значений, например, с помощью `сплайнов.`*

---

В случае вашей точки разрыва при вычислении `tan(pi / 2)`, достаточно взять соседние точки на сетке и произвести интерполяцию между ними. Насколько я знаю, построители графиков типа `Microsoft Math` именно так и поступают.